# jquery dataTables.js and its corresponding compatibile jquery.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently working on some changes which require enabling vertical scroll bar for a dynamic table. So I need to implement this vertical scroll bar mechanism on an existing table.

The existing code in our project uses `dataTables.js version 1.5.2` and `jquery-1.4.3.min.js`.

I see that vertical scroll bar property is implemented in a newer version of `dataTables.js 1.10.19.So`, my question is if i override the older version of `dataTables.js` with `1.10.19` newer one, should i override any other dependencies like `jquery.js`  and etc.. I tried it with just replacing the `dataTables.js` but could not get the desired result.

Can someone please advice on this?

Comment: You only need to update library file. Which is dataTable.js

Answer (score 0):

You'll need jQuery 1.7 or newer will work for it according to their [docs](https://datatables.net/manual/installation).